# WordPress Visual Editor - Colorize Shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, wp-editor

I want to highlight shortcodes in the WordPress visual editor in a specific color. 
E.g. I Have the following Shortcodes

```
[shortcode1] Some text [/shortcode1]
              ...
[shortcode2] Some text [/shortcode2]
```

and want to give each of them a unique color, so the user could easily see what he should change.

I have found some solutions to syntax highlighting the HTML Editor but no one for the visual editor itself. Do you know a plugin to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get a working solution.

What you need:

TinyMCE Advanced plugin

What you should do:

Customize the Visual Blocks Plugin that comes with the TinyMCE plugin and add css classes for each element you would to highlight (just loop through all p elements and parse the innerHTML and check if it contains your specific pattern).

Finally it looks something like this:
[image]

**EDIT**

The class you need to customize: ... /plugins/tinymce-advanced/mce/visualblocks/**plugin.min.js**

The **window.NodeList && (a.addCommand("mceVisualBlocks", function() {** method is the place that you need to customize. Just insert some code at the beginning of the method:

```
var elements = a.getDoc().getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        // here you should do some Regex or simple string contains string check
        // of the innerHTML and set the css class of the element. E.g.:

 if((elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf("foo") >= 0 
     && elements[i].className.indexOf("baz") < 0){
            elements[i].className = "baz";
 }
}
```

In the same directory you find css/**visualblocks.css**
You should add some css according to your customization like this:

```
.mce-visualblocks .baz {
    background-color: red;
}
```

*You can toggle the highlighting within the Visual editor in top menu bar (View->Show Blocks).*

If I have time I will work on a better solution, but this fulfill all requirements I have at the moment.